# Automate with python the navigation through a GUI

Tags: python, windows, automation

so I want to automate a simple program, this program opens up, it asks me for a prompt to press OK, it is always centered in the screen,  once this is in it then asks for 2 different text boxes which I just have to type a name, and a folder location. After this it asks for the windows user credentials and then press ok.

I have some python knowledge however during my research I have not found a library that would allow me to do this, is there a python library that I can use to be able to program this, in the sense that I want the python program to open a program (assume the program is closed and that I have a shortcut or a .exe in a folder I know). Wait a few seconds then click all the boxes and fill all the text boxes?

Comment: It would be better if you provide some screenshots from your pc when it starts, so we have a better picture of your problem.

Comment: See [**pyautogui**](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Also check the documentation of your program - it may be possible to provide all the information via the command line.

Comment: pyautogui might be what I need, and no, I already checked documentation of the software I want to automate, its legacy out of date software that does not have GUI and other software which relies on Java VM with GUI only.